# spring framevork и hibernate 6

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

как можно подключить hibernate 6 к spring framework 5.

если в мавене подключаю так

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

с такой настройкой

```
@Bean     
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() { 
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("ru.sergalas.firstApp.models");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;     
    }
```

при запуске получаю ошибку `Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)`

если делаю так

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.4.33.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

при обновлении мавена получаю  `Cannot resolve org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:5.4.33.Final`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на сaмом деле для подгрузки hibernate 5 помогло manven clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Версии Hibernate 5.4.33.Final не существует.
Здесь все версии Hibernate: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core

Я бы рекомендовал использовать 6.1.3.Final пока не будут устранены потенциальные проблемы в совместимости.

Comment: с настройкой 
```@Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new  LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("ru.sergalas.firstApp.models");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }```
у tomcat такая ошибка Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder

Comment: Вы не исключаете возможность причины исключений из-за этого бина? Без него все работает как ожидается?

Comment: боюсь без этой настройки не сработает сессия hibernate